# How to clean up temporary files after exec-ing inside entrypoint script?

Tags: mysql, docker, named-pipes, entry-point, bash-trap

I am trying to write my own mariadb docker image. I wanted to execute some sql statements just after container starts (After `exec mysqld`). However I found `mysqld --init-file` option useful for my case. So my entrypoint script is something like below.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add mariadb mariadb-client \
    && mkdir -p /run/mysqld \
    && chown -R mysql:mysql /run/mysqld \
    && ln -snf /usr/lib/mariadb /usr/lib/mysql \
    && mysql_install_db --user=mysql --skip-name-resolve --auth-root-authentication-method=socket --auth-root-socket-user=root --force --rpm --skip-test-db

   COPY entrypoint.sh /
   ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
   EXPOSE 3306

   CMD ["mysqld"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ex
{
    echo  "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}';"
    echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
    echo  "GRANT ALL ON ${MYSQL_DATABASE}.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';"
} > /tmp/mysqld-init.sql


exec $@ --init-file="/tmp/mysqld-init.sql"
```

As you can see the temporary init file contains some sensitive information. I wanted to clean it after execution of `exec $@ --init-file="/tmp/mysqld-init.sql"`.

Now two ideas came to my mind. One is to create a named pipe (FIFO) file for temporary sql command or to use trap command.

**Idea-1**

But the problem here is a unnecessary child background process is keep running on container as I have used process control operator `&`. But I am in vain how can I exit that process.

```
if [ ! -p "/tmp/mysqld.init" ]; then
    mkfifo /tmp/mysqld.init
fi

{
    echo  "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}';"
    echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
    echo  "GRANT ALL ON ${MYSQL_DATABASE}.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';"
} > /tmp/mysqld.init &

exec $@ --init-file="/tmp/mysqld.init"
```

**Idea-2**

Use trap command and clean the temporary file when `exec` command gets executed. But I don't know how to catch the exec signal.

```
trap cleanup "the exec signal"

cleanup()
{
  echo "Caught Signal ... cleaning up."
  rm -rf /tmp/mysqld-init.sql
  echo "Done cleanup ... quitting."
  exit 1
}
  set -ex
{
    echo  "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}';"
    echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
    echo  "GRANT ALL ON ${MYSQL_DATABASE}.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';"
} > /tmp/mysqld-init.sql

exec $@ --init-file="/tmp/mysqld.init"
```

Comment: you can remove the init file but what will happen with the environment variables? are you going to unset them?

Comment: I think it can be unset using file_env  https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/db27681a5753e6f22eb73b5a9575d6b833ba1238/10.3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L25. However for now I am leaving it. But how can I remove the temp file.

Comment: The environment variables will be visible both in `docker inspect` and `ps` output.  A file in `/tmp` in a container is probably a little _more_ hidden than that, and will be cleaned up automatically when the container exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) to solve this signal and zombie process issue.

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb mariadb-client tini \
    && mkdir -p /run/mysqld \
    && chown -R mysql:mysql /run/mysqld \
    && ln -snf /usr/lib/mariadb /usr/lib/mysql \
    && mysql_install_db --user=mysql --skip-name-resolve --auth-root-authentication-method=socket --auth-root-socket-user=root --force --rpm --skip-test-db

COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
if [ ! -p "/tmp/mysqld.init" ]; then
    mkfifo /tmp/mysqld.init
fi

{
    echo  "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}';"
    echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
    echo  "GRANT ALL ON ${MYSQL_DATABASE}.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';"
} > /tmp/mysqld.init &

    exec tini -g -- "$@" --init-file="/tmp/mysqld.init"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `trap` is a best solution for this

```
function interrupt(){

    local dir=$1
    [ -e ${dir} ] && rm -rf ${dir}
    exit 128
}
TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/entrypoint.XXXX)
trap "interrupt ${TMP_DIR}" SIGINT SIGTERM
trap "rm -rf ${TMP_DIR}" EXIT

set -ex
{
    echo  "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}';"
    echo  "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
    echo  "GRANT ALL ON ${MYSQL_DATABASE}.* TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'%';"
} > ${TMP_DIR}/mysqld-init.sql

exec $@ --init-file="${TMP_DIR}/mysqld-init.sql"
```

Comment: Ahh.. It doesn't work. It deletes the file before `exec`. [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/entrypoint.aJkdJB/mysqld-init.sql' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2019-01-19  1:25:06 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: It says permission denied. Try to change the temp dir to another folder with appropriate permissions

Comment: I can confirm this is not related to permission denied. As the file doesn't exist or deletes before exec main proces so mysqld displays this error.

Comment: `Can't create/write to file '/tmp/entrypoint.aJkdJB/mysqld-init.sql'` it failed to create the file, so it doesn't exist. Play with it, add debug messages etc

Comment: As I told in above comment, I checked it properly that it is able to create the temp file but deletes before executing mysqld command. I am sure because I am running the script as root. That is a mysqld error.

Comment: and what is the user that `mysqld` is running with?  I'm pretty sure it is something related to your image setup. Also add debug messages and you will figure out when the files is being removed exactly

Comment: Okay. My bad. Mysqld runs as user mysql. How ever I added `chmod -R 777 ${TMP_DIR}` and that permission denied error went away. But the temp file doesn't remove itself. It is still there.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense since exec doesn't finish, I've missed that point. I'll play with it later